# Multilanguage website - with different posts or same posts???Weird

Tags: web-development, multilingual

So lets say I have a website en and de.
[www.example.com/en](http://www.example.com/en)
[www.example.com/de](http://www.example.com/de)

So I make a post about cars:
[www.example.com/en/cars](http://www.example.com/en/cars)    - very similar but not the exact translation
[www.example.com/de/autos](http://www.example.com/de/autos)   - very similar but not the exact translation

1. will both results show up in google ? some people post some fancy words some href bla bla and say only one language will get indexed. Well how is that useful?

I mean if Germans can not see the german post in their little google.de? Then why even make a multilingual website?

Comment: Who is saying that only one language will get indexed?   It would be helpful to link to articles or videos where you heard this.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118603/hreflang-duplicate-content-on-a-multi-language-website

"With the rel=canonical across languages (eg, de -> canonical -> en), you're saying that these pages are equivalent and that you have a preference regarding which URL to index. If that's the case, if you think the translated boilerplate doesn't add more value (which might be the case), then that (I'd call it "canonical language") seems like a good setup."

i hope yous ee this because this forum never notifies people that i replied and people rarely reply back

Comment: ohh!! it was you!!

Comment: John Mueller wrote that. I only did some minor edits.

Comment: Are you using canonical tags between your English cars page and your German autos page?

Comment: I don't even know what canonical tags mean

Comment: currently I am not using anything that's for sure :D